# Why isn't my postgres docker container mounting the database?

Tags: postgresql, docker

So I have two docker images which are used to host postgres servers.  One is for first time setup and puts a .sh and .sql script into the appropriate directory for postgres to load them up (which works as expect).  The second image is for running any other time where the database has already been created.  The docker files for these looks like this:

```
FROM postgres:9.3

RUN mkdir -p /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

ADD Setup.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sh
ADD schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.sql

VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]
```

and

```
FROM postgres:9.3
MAINTAINER Andrew Broadbent <andrew.broadbent@manchester.ac.uk>

RUN mkdir -p /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]
```

I run the first from the following shell script:

```
# Create the volumes for the data backend database.
docker volume create --name psql-data-etc
docker volume create --name psql-data-log
docker volume create --name psql-data-lib

# Create data store database
echo -e "\n${TITLE}[Data Store Database]${NC}"
read -p " User name: " user
read -s -p " Password: " password
echo ""
read -p " Database name: " dbname
docker run -v psql-data-etc:/etc/postgresql -v psql-data-log:/var/log/postgresql -v psql-data-lib:/var/lib/postgresql -e "NEW_USER=$user" -e "NEW_PASSWORD=$password" -e "POSTGRES_DB=$dbname" -p 9001:5432 -P -d --name psql-data postgres-setup-datastore
```

and I run the second from the following:

```
echo -e "\n${TITLE}[Data Store Database]${NC}"
read -p " User name: " user
read -s -p " Password: " password
docker run -v psql-data-etc:/etc/postgresql -v psql-data-log:/var/log/postgresql -v psql-data-lib:/var/lib/postgresql -e "POSTGRES_USER=$user" -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$password" -p 9001:5432 -P --name psql-data postgres-runtime
```

If I run the first script, connect the the database make some changes, then remove the container, then run the second script, the changes I made to the database aren't persisted.  How do I persist them?  I managed to get it working earlier, but I'm not sure what I've changed and can't seem to get it working any more.

Comment: The postgres image itself defines a volume at `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, but you defined another volume at its parent directory. I wonder if that is causing the trouble.

Comment: I'll give it another try, but just before posting this, I wasn't creating any volumes in my images.

Comment: You are in fact correct.